# regex split in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split a time between the digits and the letters. For example, if i have the time ''1000hours" I need to make array using regex like that ["1000","hours"]. I want to do that with seconds (s)    minutes (m)    hours (h)    days (d)    weeks (w). So I decided to find the first letter I need (s/m/h/d/w) and then split the word. In the regex site it works, but in the code it doesnt. I didn't include 'g' in the end of regex so it would stop in the first match, but it didn't.

1. Site:
   [Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RBIN.png)
2. Code:

   var time = "3000hours"

   const reg1 = /(?=s)|(?=m)|(?=h)|(?=d)|(?=w)/

   const hours = time.split(reg1)

   console.log(hours);

(result in code: ['3000', 'hour', 's'])          but i want ['3000', 'hours']

Answer (score 1):

`split` always continues to split even if you provide a regex without `g`.
You can change the regex to require that the split only occurs after a digit. Note that you can use a character class:

```js
var time = "3000hours";
const reg1 = /(?<=\d)(?=[smhdw])/;
const hours = time.split(reg1);
console.log(hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @trincot's answer if your browser supports negative lookbehind, e.g. all but Safari.

Here is a solution using `.match()`:

```js
[
  "3000hours",
  "59minutes",
  "3hours",
  "4weeks"
].forEach(str => {
  let arr = str.match(/^(\d+)(.*)$/).splice(1, 2);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

Output:

```
["3000","hours"]
["59","minutes"]
["3","hours"]
["4","weeks"]
```

Explanation:

- `.match(/^(\d+)(.*)$/)` -- match two capture groups: 1. digits, 2. anything following the digits
- `.splice(1, 2)` -- keep only the 2nd and 3rd item of the array